# Overriding the underline from a bootstrap accordion's header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am playing with the Bootstrap accordion & can't seem to be able to remove the underline/border which is displayed when the heading is open.

The accordion-heading style doesn't seem to specify a border and I can't locate where it's coming from using an element inspector.

The yellow highlighted line is what I am interested in (I have no trouble overriding the other borders.

[image: Header underline/border]

Any tips?

Comment: Links: [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WdYHN/) or the [bootstrap docs](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.accordion-inner` (below the header, encapsulates the accordion content) has a `border-top` property specified. This is probably what you're looking to modify/remove. The following CSS snippet will remove the border you're referencing.

```
.accordion-inner { border-top: 0 none; }
```